# how to make animation with for loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x

how to make animation with foor loops?
The animation does not work, if run start -> graphs are overlaped...

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.animation as animation

df = pd.read_excel('D:\\python\\221027_phdiagram.xlsx', sheet_name=3)
df_sat = pd.read_excel('D:\\python\\221027_phdiagram.xlsx', sheet_name=2)

st=0
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
x=[]
y=[]
ims1=[]
ims2=[]
ims3=[]
ims4=[]
ims5=[]
for st in range(0,3600,600):
    
    x1=df.loc[st,'h1']    y1=df.loc[st,'P1']    z1=df.loc[st,'시간']    x2=df.loc[st,'h2']
    y2=df.loc[st,'P2']    z2=df.loc[st,'시간']    x3=df.loc[st,'h3']    y3=df.loc[st,'P3']
    z3=df.loc[st,'시간']    x6=df.loc[st,'h6']    y6=df.loc[st,'P6']    z6=df.loc[st,'시간']
    x7=df.loc[st,'h7']    y7=df.loc[st,'P7']    z7=df.loc[st,'시간']    x8=df.loc[st,'h8']
    y8=df.loc[st,'P8']    z8=df.loc[st,'시간']
    
    sat_y=df_sat.loc[3:1203,'pbar']
    sat_liq_x=df_sat.loc[3:1203,'hliquid']
    sat_vap_x=df_sat.loc[3:1203,'hvapor']
    plt.yscale('log',base=10)

    sat_curve1=plt.plot(sat_liq_x,sat_y,color='b')
    sat_curve2=plt.plot(sat_vap_x,sat_y,color='b')
    
    x=[x1,x2,x3,x6,x7,x8]
    y=[y1,y2,y3,y6,y7,y8]

    curveline=plt.plot(x,y,marker='o',color='r')
    curvex=plt.xlabel('Enthalpy')
    curvey=plt.ylabel('Pressure')
    plt.xticks([140,200,260,320,380,440,500,560])
    plt.yticks([0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,20,30,40,50])
    #ims1.append([sat_curve1])
    #ims2.append([sat_curve2])
    #ims3.append([curveline])
    #ims4.append([curvex])
    #ims5.append([curvey])
    
    
#rint(st)
ani = FuncAnimation(fig,sat_curve1,frames=200,interval=50)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [so] is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.